# Replacing every nth occurrence of a string by n + string in text file

Tags: python, string, replace

A text file contains

```
This is line ABC XYZ. This is something. This is ABC XYZ. foo. This is ABC XYZ. foo
```

The required output is

```
This is line 1 ABC XYZ. This is something. This is 2 ABC XYZ. foo. This is 3 ABC XYZ. foo
```

So the problem is to replace nth occurrence of **ABC XYZ** by ***n* ABC XYZ**.

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 2):

The method `re.sub` can take a function as second argument. Use a stateful function with an `itertools.count` object as counter.

### Code

```
import re, itertools

s = 'This is line ABC XYZ. This is something. This is ABC XYZ. foo. This is ABC XYZ. foo'

def enumerator():
    counter = itertools.count(1)

    return lambda m: '{} {}'.format(next(counter), m.group())

out = re.sub(r'ABC XYZ', enumerator(), s)

print(out)
```

The function `enumerator` can be reused for any pattern.

### Output

```
This is line 1 ABC XYZ. This is something. This is 2 ABC XYZ. foo. This is 3 ABC XYZ. foo
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension

```
a="This is line ABC XYZ. This is something. This is ABC XYZ. foo. This is ABC XYZ. foo"
''.join([e+str(c+1)+" ABC XYZ" for c,e in enumerate(a.split("ABC XYZ"))][0:-1])+a.split("ABC XYZ.")[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code**:

```
import re

text = "This is line ABC XYZ. This is something. This is ABC XYZ. foo. This is ABC XYZ. foo"
x = re.split("(ABC XYZ)",text)
c=0
for i,s in enumerate(x):
    if re.match('(ABC XYZ)',x[i]):
        c+=1
        x[i] = str(c)+' '+x[i]
x = ''.join(x)   # This is line 1 ABC XYZ. This is something. This is 2 ABC XYZ. foo. This is 3 ABC XYZ. foo
```

You can use more optimized ways of doing this, however this would help you understand it better.